# Dissect a sphere into infinitely many cylinders that have a total volume same with that of the sphere

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose a cylinder with radius r and height r is put on the ground.

Then, another cylinder with radius $\frac{1}{2r}$ and height r is placed on top of the initial cylinder.

After that, cylinders that have $\frac{1}{2}$ of the radius of the previous cylinder and the same height r are placed on top of each other.

The result is that the total volume of the cylinders is equal to the volume of a sphere with radius r.

Here is my approach:

$$V_{cylinder} = \pi r^2h$$
$$h=r$$
 $$V_{cylinder} = \pi r^3$$
$$\displaystyle V_{tot,cylinders} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\pi r^3 = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = V_{sphere}$$
Am I doing this correctly?

[image]
[image]
*Figure not drawn to scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fine.

It works because of the geometric sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac14}=\frac43$$

Remark:

When you write $V_{cylinder}$, you might like to mention which one are you referring to.